# Geneos: How to capture sql-toolkit column value and use inside a rule?

Tags: variables, rule, geneos

So, I have sql-toolkit sampler setup which runs a query  select a,b from c where some condition.
I also have a rule setup, target being number of rows returned by above sampler, idea being: if number of rows > 0, then raise an alarm.

That works just fine; what I need to know is, how can I capture returned value of column "a" and use it inside the rule to, for instance, format Subject.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to use a geneos column value inside a rule, then you need to define the target in your rule. The easiest way to do this would be to

- Right click on the column you want to access
- Copy From (Second Option in the list)
- And then select path

once the path is copied, it can be pasted in the target field of the rule. And then you can define your rule something like this:

[image]